# A basic problem on weak convergence

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Let $f_n$ be $2^n$ times the indicator of the set of $x$ in the unit interval for which the digit from $n+1$ to $2n$ is zero in the dyadic expansion of $x$ (lets call it $A_n$). I have to show that the distributions corresponding to these densities converge weakly to Lebesgue measure confined to the unit interval.

In other words, $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{y}2^n \chi_{A_n}= y.$$ How ? I can't use any DCT/BCT here.

Comment: A little tip: you can use `\to` to represent $\to$.

Comment: Hint: if $n\geqslant k$, the fact that one is in $A_n$ does not depend on the $k$ first digits in one's binary expansion.

Comment: @Did : I am not understanding the hint.